# font-size difference between opera and firefox

Tags: html, cross-browser, font-size

I found my page text displayed in opera and firefox with different font-size.

```
         <div id='kfbuttext1'>
             <a href='#' class='kfbutlink'>test string</a>
             <a href='#' class='kfbutlink'>line 2</a>
         </div>
```

CSS  as follows .kfbutlink{Font-family:arial; font-size:12px}. it looks fine it firefox but opera(9.64) displays it large size.

Comment: What version of Opera? There is no version 9.4, although there is 9.64. Why not test against v10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera has many features to automatically zoom the fonts to make the page more viewable. If you have fit-to-width enabled, the fonts will appear larger.